# Fetch() running out of order

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I am trying to have an API pull a word and set it to state. Then a function will read that state and complete its designed purpose. However, the way I originally coded it called it out of order. The third code snippet allows the code to run successfully, but I am not sure why. Could someone explain what the difference is or why the original way did not work?

Below is the API function followed by the second function:

```
wordNikApi = () => {
        fetch("http://api.wordnik.com:80/v4/words.json/randomWords?hasDictionaryDef=true&minCorpusCount=0&minLength=5&maxLength=15&limit=1&api_key=/* Removed */")
            .then( res => res.json() )
            .then( ( result ) => {
                this.setState({
                    apiWord: result[0].word,
                });
                console.log("wordNikApi: ", this.state.apiWord);
            })
            .catch( ( error ) => {
                console.log("API ERROR: ", error);
            })
    };
```

```
resetGame = () => {

        console.log("resetGame");

        this.wordNikApi();

        this.setState({ 
            word: [],
            count: 0,
            allAttempts: [],
            letterIndex: [],
            numberOfBadAttempts: 0,
            remainingAttempts: 6,
            repeat: false,
            pageLock: false,
            invalidKey: false,
        }, () => {

            console.log("resetGame: function 1");

            console.log(this.state.apiWord);

            let fullWord = "word";
            let wordArray = fullWord.split("");
            let wordLength = wordArray.length;

            // Send wordObj to state with value and index
            let wordObj = wordArray.map((value, index) => {
                return {
                    found: false,
                    val: value,
                    id: index,
                }
            })

            this.setState({ 
                word: wordObj,
                wordLength: wordLength,
                remainingAttempts: 6,
            });
        });


    };
```

Functioning code:

```
resetGame = () => {

        console.log("resetGame");

        // this.wordNikApi();

        fetch("http://api.wordnik.com:80/v4/words.json/randomWords?hasDictionaryDef=true&minCorpusCount=0&minLength=5&maxLength=15&limit=1&api_key=/* Removed */")
            .then( res => res.json() )
            .then( ( result ) => {
                this.setState({
                    apiWord: result[0].word,
                }, ()=> {
            
                    let fullWord = this.state.apiWord;
                    let wordArray = fullWord.split("");
                    let wordLength = wordArray.length;
        
                    // Send wordObj to state with value and index
                    let wordObj = wordArray.map((value, index) => {
                        return {
                            found: false,
                            val: value,
                            id: index,
                        }
                    })
        
                    this.setState({ 
                        word: wordObj,
                        wordLength: wordLength,
                        remainingAttempts: 6,
                        count: 0,
                        allAttempts: [],
                        letterIndex: [],
                        numberOfBadAttempts: 0,
                        repeat: false,
                        pageLock: false,
                        invalidKey: false,
                    });
                });
            })
            .catch( ( error ) => {
                console.log("API ERROR: ", error);
            })
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is causing you a problem is the JS asynchronism, when you call the wordNikApi function within the resetGame function, you must use the await keyword, so that in this way the changes to the wordNijApi function are generated first and then continue with the flow of work. Try modifying the resetGame function like this:

```js
const resetGame = async()=>{
...

await this.wordNikApi()
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Fetch is an asynchronous function, which means it will run along side your other code, calling `this.wordNikApi()` sets the fetch request going but doesn't stop you script from continuing.

In your new version you have the code inside the `.then()` function which is what is called when the fetch request has called for the data and returned so your code inside here is waiting for `this.wordNikApi()` to finish before running in the 3rd snippet.

Hope this helped clear up Async and Sync a bit more, however there are better documents out there to explain this.

Comment: That is explained perfectly. Using what you said along with the solution Roso gave should work to make the script function as desired. Thank you!

Comment: Great! Best of luck with the rest of your project.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but thought others may can use this.
I implemented a queue that calls fetch on the first item in the queue, then uses fetch().then to pull the next item, post it, then recurs if the queue is not empty. Here's the code I used:

```
var clientDataQueue = [];
function queueClientData(theData) {
    clientDataQueue.push(theData);
    console.log("++clientDataQueue.length:", clientDataQueue.length)
    if (clientDataQueue.length == 1){
        postFromQueue();
    }
}

function postFromQueue() {
    console.log("--clientDataQueue.length:", clientDataQueue.length)
    if (clientDataQueue.length > 0) {
        postClientdata(clientDataQueue[0]).then( () => {
            clientDataQueue.shift();
            postFromQueue();
        });
    }
}

function postClientdata(theData) {
    var htmlData = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(theData)
    };
    return fetch('/api/clientData', htmlData)
}
```